# Impala/SQL How can I put all the orther fields on a group by statement?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a query grouped by 3 fields against 100 fields table. How can I put the another 97 fields in the select without a join?

This is my statement:

```
select a,b,c,max(d) as max_d
from mytable
group by a,b,c;
```

I know that the following query works, but it's very heavy :(

```
select mytable.* from
(
    select a,b,c,max(d) as max_d
from mytable
group by a,b,c
) uni
join mytable myt (uni.a=mytable.a AND uni.b=mytable.b AND uni.c=mytable.c AND uni.max_d=mytable.d);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(d) over (partition by a, b, c) as max_d
      from mytable t
where d = max_d;
```

Comment: It says suggested edit queue is full...

select t.*
from (select a.*, max(d) over (partition by a, b, c) as max_d
      from mytable a) t
where t.d = max_d;

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery instead :

```
select mt.*
from mytable mt
where mt.d = (select max(mt1.d)
              from mytable mt1
              where mt1.a = mt.a and mt1.b = mt.b and mt1.c = mt.c
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use co-related subquery

```
select t.* from mytable t
where t.d in ( select max(d) from mytable t1 
         where t1.a=t.a and t1.b=t.b and t1.c=t.c
              )
```